# How to get number of keys for a nested value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where keys have the same values.

```
products = {
    1: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    2: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    3: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    4: {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
}
```

I'm looking for the fastest method to get their count without going into two for loops to compare them (since I'm working with 10000+ such key, value pairs)

```
{1:1, 2:2, 3:3}: 3
{1:2, 2:3, 3:4}: 1
```

The only solutions I could find was using `collection.Counter` but since it's a nested dictionary, it doesn't work. I could work with a list instead, but it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the dictionaries into frozensets of their items. Those are hashable, so you can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in products.values())
for k, v in ctr.items():
    print(dict(k), v)
```

Output:

```
{1: 1, 3: 3, 2: 2} 3
{2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 4} 1
```

Benchmark results ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLBboMwDL3zFb5UJVuECvQwIfU0aX@wUzVFNIQtAxIUQtet6rczJ0DbTa1PyXu237OT9tt@aJU@tWYYSqMbsLIR0oJsWm3sdAs8w3VdC26lVt1MP@teWWGCoBAlvMYJe9HmKzdF2Bpd9Nx2JAsA4wAb2D7MYLTP6150IXnzpBG2Nwq2YcEthUPEXVN3IQRKbQBPIBXcqPayhVaW2byu2GffWcZ1If7Lc2vQwGQ2xGF@hOoEakTSigZbTUI3Zcg/k5LbsCIU9mNRhSdXhxpzNzRW9op3qHm1E3rLaRDMeph89EpxBsc4iykkWUIhzdIT9XhyB0/v4GuPJw5PHb4@Bae/cvKxytD89RTn6adRPCkdY3L1LsIVhXiFQWFNsJtj2YVNp3072G3AMX4TI@zCovD4qcI6b3ZFnvmMy4tRUH2zE2YTk3NRayT@iOUiSkvoYAkLwI/iyiLGVN4IxsbcMY8Mwy8)):

```
2.586 s  U12_Forward
0.007 s  dont_talk_just_code
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import Counter

def U12_Forward(products):
    x = [*products.values()]
    return [(dct, x.count(dct)) for dct in products.values()]

def dont_talk_just_code(products):
    ctr = Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in products.values())
    return [(dict(k), v) for k, v in ctr.items()]

funcs = U12_Forward, dont_talk_just_code

products = {
    1: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    2: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    3: {1:1, 2:2, 3:3},
    4: {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
}

products = {i+k: v for k, v in products.items() for i in range(0, 10000, 4)}

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: func(products), number=1)
        print('%.3f s ' % t, func.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
>>> x = [*products.values()]
>>> {x.count(dct): dct for dct in products.values()}
{3: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 1: {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}}
>>>
```

Comment: That's supposed to be *"the fastest method"*?

Comment: Also, what if another dictionary appears three times. You'll lose one of them.